# Why is gcd(c,d)=1 for $M \in SL_2(\mathbb(Z))$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have an idea but I am not entirely sure if it is right.

Since $M \in SL_2(Z)$, $ad-bc=1$. Can we use Bézout's Lemma here to get the proposition? I know it only says that it is for ad+bc=ggt(a,b), but maybe it could be possible to choose appropriate $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ to get the lemma for ad-bc=1 too? Thanks for your help

Comment: it is obvious that $gcd(c,d)$ divides $ad-bc$ (where every integer divides $0$) It is in the opposite direction that it is non-trivial, that is there exists $a,b$ such that $ad-bc = gcd(c,d)$, and that you need the Euclid algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if $c$ and $d$ have a factor in common, say $m$? Specifically, assume $c=km$ and $d=lm$. Then $$ad-bc=alm-bkm=m(al-bk)$$Can that last expression equal $1$ if $m>1$?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Bezout. It is enough to review the equation $ad-bc=1$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. If $m=gcd(c,d)$, then $m\mid c$ and $m\mid d$ by definition, so that
the equation implies $m\mid 1$. Hence $m=1$.

Comment: But does bezout also works for ad-bc in general?×

Comment: Bezout does always work in general. But you only need divisibility, which is much easier: If $m\mid c,d$, then $m\mid (ad-bc)=r$, and $r$ need not be $1$.